# Combine two nginx location rewrite

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

Am I using these two rewrites in my nginx site conf:

**http://site/purchased/new/** becomes **http://site/index.php?page=newPurchaseForm/** with this rewrite

```
rewrite ^/purchased/new/?$ /index.php?page=newPurchaseForm;
```

**http://site/purchased/new/9999/** becomes **http://site/index.php?page=newPurchaseForm&userId=9999** with this rewrite

```
rewrite ^/purchased/new/([0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?page=newPurchaseForm&userId=$1;
```

Am I using them the right way or could I create one rewrite to deal with both requests?